# How to fix endpointscfg.py to generate discovery doc for Endpoints API? (Missing oauth2client.anyjson)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

As of this writing, it seems the endpointscfg.py script that comes with Google App Engine is broken. I'm trying to generate an iOS client for my Endpoints API written in Python. According to the [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/consume_ios), generating a discovery doc with the `endpointscfg.py` script is required first. But doing so gives this error:

```
 File "/myproject/libs/googleapiclient/errors.py", line 27, in <module>
from oauth2client.anyjson import simplejson
```

ImportError: No module named anyjson

The problem is that the included oauth2client in my Google App Engine comes with oauth2client version 1.3.2 and `anyjson.py` was [removed in version 1.3](https://github.com/google/oauth2client/blob/fd054dcdcc5f6a4d3a0b7a29f410f415f342044c/CHANGELOG.md). It seems like Google hasn't updated their `endpointscfg.py` script to work with this change. What would be the cleanest solution to fix this without waiting for Google?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me more like you are using an old `googleapiclient` that still requires it, as the trace is in that package. That library was updated last year in [this commit](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/commit/6ae34d7532740c7a51276aa2e30242aa5aca252a).

Comment: Thanks saiyr. I see the problem now and updated that library. How did you discover that was the problem?

Comment: File "/myproject/libs/googleapiclient/errors.py", line 27 points to the external library. –  saiyr May 13 at 16:59 (reposted and updated to remove personal information, can't edit comments past a certain point)

Comment: This answer really helped me out, I ended up going to https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/downloads/list and downloading google-api-python-client-1.2.zip then exported the following two folders:  apiclient and googleapiclient.  After this I was then able to complete my task!

Comment: I got it working by running this command  pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client